# Показать скрытый div и плавно прокрутить страницу к нему

Tags: javascript, html, animate

Имеется Div с `style="display:none"` плюс кнопка для его открытия и перехода к этому блоку. Проблема в том что переходит очень быстро, а как в этот код вписать `animate()` вместо `scrollIntoView()` с сохранением `toggle()` понятия не имею.

```
<script>
$('#showForm').click(function(){
  $('.formL').toggle("slow", function() {
    $('.formL').get(0).scrollIntoView()
  }); 
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$('#showForm').click(function() {
  $('.formL').toggle(foo);
});

function foo() {
  let x = $(this);
  $('body').animate({
    scrollTop: x.offset().top
  }, 1500);
}
```

```css
#content {
  height: 1300px;
}

.formL {
  display: none;
  width: 130px;
  height: 35px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id='showForm'>click me</button>
<div style="height:150px;"></div>
<div class="formL">111111111</div>
<div id='content'></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно попробовать так:

```js
$('#showForm').click(function() {
  var parrent = $('#parrent');
  var element = $('.formL');
  element.toggle("slow", scrollFunc(parrent, element));
});

function scrollFunc(parrent, element) {
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: parseInt($(element).css("margin-top"), 10) - $(element).height()
  }, {
    duration: 'slow',
    easing: 'swing'
  });
}
```

```css
.parrent {
  height: 1000px;
}

.formL {
  display: none;
  background: red;
  margin-top: 150px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="parrent" class="parrent">
  <button id='showForm'>click me</button>
  <div class="formL">Hello</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/qtargk7e/68/

вариант использования setInterval, без animate()

```js
$('#showForm').click(function() { 
    $('.formL').toggle(foo); 
});
$('#showForm').html('показать єлемент и сместить скролл к нему');
var scrolling = null;
var curThis = null;
function foo() {
  
  scrolling = setInterval(baa,10); 
  curThis = $(this);
  
}
function baa(){
  if($(window).scrollTop() < curThis.offset().top-6)//offsetting
       window.scrollTo(0,$(window).scrollTop()+6);
  else{
       clearInterval(scrolling);
    curThis = null;
    }
}
```

```css
#content {
  height: 1300px;
}

.formL {
  display: none;
  width: 130px;
  height: 35px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id='showForm'></button>
<div style="height:150px;"></div>
<div class="formL"></div>
<div id='content'></div>
```